# Cannot use generic key on objectwith conditional key

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble using a generic as a key for an object

```
interface Foo {
    prop1: string | null,
    prop2: string | null,
    prop3?: number
}

const updateFoo = <K extends keyof Foo>(
    key: K,
    payload: Foo[K] | null
): Array<Foo> => {
    let somthingToEditUpdated = {} as Foo;
    somthingToEditUpdated[key] = payload;

    return []
}
```

> Type 'Foo[K] | null' is not assignable to type 'Foo[K]'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Foo[K]'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'never'.

If I remove `prop3?: number` from the `Foo interface` it works. Why?

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIAOU6RAjAFzIDOYUoA5sgD7IgCuANlwDT6ESZAEzU6DEMzace-QsVJEAzAH5qnALYAjaLgC%20uXAnQg6yAPociAEziQAymDLoAbtGQBeZAB4A0sggAD0gQaxpkAGsIAE90GDRMAD4ACgECKOjqXzlBOGiudDhragx0AG1fAF1Wdm4uXABKagBBKCg871LEz268eS4IMFp0DTAACyYAFXQAUWtgMABVGzsIa08cPWQ4cNKAbjTh0YnJabmF5dtIazKM6q8iPIKig8OoQY4oEGQyyv0gA)

Comment: "*If I remove prop3?: number from the Foo interface it works. Why?*" because all other values accept a `null`, but `prop3` does not. So assigning something potentially nullable would work for `prop1` and `prop2` but not for `prop3`. And `payload` is potentially nullable.

Comment: @VLAZ is there a way to solve this without adding `null` to `prop3`?

Comment: Why not simply `payload: Foo[K]`? Thus you can pass string or null to both prop1 and prop2, but for prop3 you can pass number or undefined

Comment: I agree with @Lesiak here; there seems to be no reason to allow `payload` to be `null` here unless `Foo[K]` already includes `null`, in which case [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxq2ZW) works as I'd expect.  If this works for you, maybe @Lesiak can write an answer.  If this *doesn't* work for you, please [edit] the question code to include a demonstration of what breaks if you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no reason to allow payload to be `null` here unless `Foo[K]` already includes `null`.

To allow the setter to accept only the accepted values, use `payload: Foo[K]`

```ts
interface Foo {
  prop1: string | null,
  prop2: string | null,
  prop3?: number
}

const updateFoo = <K extends keyof Foo>(
  key: K,
  payload: Foo[K]
): Array<Foo> => {
  let somthingToEditUpdated = {} as Foo;
  somthingToEditUpdated[key] = payload;
  return []
}
```

Thus:

- `prop1` accepts `string` or `null`
- `prop2` accepts `string` or `null`
- `prop3` accepts `number` or `undefined`

More generally, if `propX` is of type `A`, it is useful for the setter to accept:

- type `A`
- subset of type `A` (like only non-null values etc)